# How to check a clockwise direction for a list of point

Tags: graphics, sorting

Suppose that we have a list of points and we need to order them in clockwise direction by starting from a special point. I implemented this code to order them but I need to detect if it is ordered in clockwise or in counterclockwise direction. Here, I start from the point {100,200} and  I create the shortest tour.

```
list = {{100, 200}, {200, 300}, {300, 300}, {320, 150}, {250, 
    210}, {350, 220}, {380, 100}, {390, 300}};

order = list[[Last@FindShortestTour[list]]]

Manipulate[Graphics[{{Green, Line[order[[1 ;; i]]]}, {Red, Point[#] & /@ order[[1 ;; i]]}}], {i, 2, Length[order], 1}]
```

Comment: Will they always be in the first quadrant of the plane? (i.e. will `x` and `y` always be positive?)

Comment: @march, x and y will be positive, suppose that we work in [0,inf[

Comment: I think you need to clarify this question by better characterizing the properties and/or constraints that can assumed for the list of points.

Answer (score 4):

This basically directly computes the angle that a line drawn from the origin to the point makes with the horizontal axis, and uses this to sort:

```
list = {{100, 200}, {200, 300}, {300, 300}, {320, 150}, {250, 210}, {350, 220}, {380, 100}, {390, 300}};
ordList = SortBy[list, Apply[N[ArcTan[#1, #2]] &]]
(* {{380, 100}, {320, 150}, {350, 220}, {390, 300}, {250, 210}, {300, 
   300}, {200, 300}, {100, 200}} *)
```

Checking:

```
 Graphics[Arrow[{#1, #2}] & @@@ Partition[Normalize /@ ordList, 2, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: suppose that we have a closed contour and we need to start from a special point i.e {100,200}. How you can modify your code?

Comment: @Developer2000 Try to state all your requirements at once. Answer refining is usually a never ending task